# Android: RadioButton within Nested Layout under RadioGroup falls out of Group

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to get some sensible positioning of my radiobuttons which are part of a RadioGroup. I was having trouble as my RadioGroup was sitting on top of the rest of my layout design, then I use margins to push the buttons around, the problem here is this works on one or two device layouts only. I thought I struck gold when I discovered I could define my RadioGroup then put in a RelativeLayout below which amongst other things contained one of the RadioButtons, then I repeat twice more. this gives me the layout I desire. Problem is, when I run the code, the RadioButtons act link standalone buttons :(

So two questions,

- can I link these buttons back to the Group?
- Is there a decent way to be able to define the layout of the RadioGroup Radiobuttons independently of the Group.

I am thinking an alternative may be independent RadioButtons and use code to enable/disable them, but that does kind of defeat the usefulness of RadioGroup.

thanks.

Here is my XML layout should you be curious.

```
    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

       android:layout_below="@id/HDDResultsBox"
        >   

    <RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:focusable="true" 
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
    > 


    <RadioGroup android:id="@+id/calcBy"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:focusable="true" 
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/HDDResultsBox"

        >

  <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/intervalBox"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="@drawable/backgroundbox"
       android:layout_margin="5dp"
       android:padding="5dp"


        >
          <TextView  android:id="@+id/intervalHeader"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Interval"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            />    

         <TextView  android:id="@+id/intervalHelpText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Interval help text"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="8dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/intervalHeader"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            /> 

           <LinearLayout  android:id="@+id/interval2ndBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_below="@id/intervalHeader"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            >
                <RadioButton android:id="@+id/byInterval"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    />

                <EditText  android:id="@+id/intervalValue"
                    android:layout_width="75dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:text="50"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="number" 
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    />    

                <Spinner android:id="@+id/intervalType"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="42dp"
                    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
                    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="10"
               android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    /> 

              <SeekBar android:id="@+id/intervalSeek"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:max="100"
               android:progress="50"
               android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
               android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
               android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
               android:layout_weight="7"
           /> 
            </LinearLayout>  

        </RelativeLayout>


 <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/recordBox"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="@drawable/backgroundbox"
       android:layout_margin="5dp"
       android:padding="5dp"


        >
          <TextView  android:id="@+id/recordHeader"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Record Duration"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            />    

         <TextView  android:id="@+id/recordHelpText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Record help text"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="8dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/recordHeader"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            /> 

           <LinearLayout  android:id="@+id/record2ndBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_below="@id/recordHeader"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            >
                <RadioButton android:id="@+id/byrecord"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    />

                <EditText  android:id="@+id/recordValue"
                    android:layout_width="75dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:text="50"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="number" 
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    />    

                <Spinner android:id="@+id/recordType"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="42dp"
                    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
                    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="10"
               android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    /> 

              <SeekBar android:id="@+id/recordSeek"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:max="100"
               android:progress="50"
               android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
               android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
               android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
               android:layout_weight="7"
           /> 
            </LinearLayout>  

        </RelativeLayout>

 <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/playBackBox"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="@drawable/backgroundbox"
       android:layout_margin="5dp"
       android:padding="5dp"


        >
          <TextView  android:id="@+id/playBackHeader"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Video Length"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            />    

         <TextView  android:id="@+id/playBackHelpText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="playBack help text"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="8dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/playBackHeader"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            /> 

           <LinearLayout  android:id="@+id/playBack2ndBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_below="@id/playBackHeader"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            >
                <RadioButton android:id="@+id/byplayBack"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    />

                <EditText  android:id="@+id/playBackValue"
                    android:layout_width="75dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:text="50"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="number" 
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    />    

                <Spinner android:id="@+id/playBackType"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="42dp"
                    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
                    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="10"
               android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    /> 

              <SeekBar android:id="@+id/playBackSeek"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:max="100"
               android:progress="50"
               android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
               android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
               android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
               android:layout_weight="7"
           /> 
            </LinearLayout>  

        </RelativeLayout>    


    </RadioGroup>           
</RelativeLayout>
        </ScrollView>
```

Comment: remove the radiogroup and handle the buttons yourself if it does not work with a radiogroup. Like on button1 click : set all others to inactive.

Comment: I'm disappointed that you can't control a group better, but I've now adjusted my code to use buttons manually. cheers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After looking around for a solution it looks the only way to do this is to use individual radio buttons and then programmically control there on/off states.

Comment: You'd think Google would've come up with a solution to this. I encountered this when building an "Other" button. Putting a TextEdit in following the button has proven to be very difficult...